# smarty template- foreach loop to display only 2 value in single row

Tags: php, smarty

I am working on a smarty template in which I have to show only 2 company name in one row  i am using this code

```
{foreach from=$found_users_sids item=user_sid name=users_block}

  <div class="{cycle values = 'evenrow,oddrow' advance=true}">

  {display property='username' object_sid=$user_sid assign='username'}

    {display property='CompanyName' object_sid=$user_sid assign='companyNameAlias'}

    {display property='State.Code' object_sid=$user_sid parent=Location assign='State'}

    {display property='City' object_sid=$user_sid parent=Location assign='City'} <span> 
    <strong><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/company/{$user_sid}/{$companyNameAlias|replace:" ":"-"|escape:"url"}/">{display property='CompanyName' object_sid=$user_sid}</a> </strong> {$City}{if $City && $State}, {/if}{$State} 
    </span> 
    </div>

  {/foreach}
```

but it showing the answer like this

```
immersive reasearch Centerville, MA
Integrated Resource Group Hartford, CT
Inventa Group Atlanta, GA
```

and i want to display it like this

```
 immersive reasearch Centerville, MA,  Integrated Resource Group Hartford, CT     
 Inventa Group Atlanta, GA
```

i would like to thanks everyone in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You should add conditional displaying beginning and end of yor div as below:

```
{foreach from=$found_users_sids item=user_sid name=users_block}
   {if $smarty.foreach.users_block.iteration mod 2 eq 1}
     <div class="{cycle values = 'evenrow,oddrow' advance=true}">
  {/if}
  {display property='username' object_sid=$user_sid assign='username'}

    {display property='CompanyName' object_sid=$user_sid assign='companyNameAlias'}

    {display property='State.Code' object_sid=$user_sid parent=Location assign='State'}

    {display property='City' object_sid=$user_sid parent=Location assign='City'} <span> 
    <strong><a href="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/company/{$user_sid}/{$companyNameAlias|replace:" ":"-"|escape:"url"}/">{display property='CompanyName' object_sid=$user_sid}</a> </strong> {$City}{if $City && $State}, {/if}{$State} 
    </span> 
    {if $smarty.foreach.users_block.iteration mod 2 eq 0 or $smarty.foreach.users_block.last}
          </div>
    {/if}

  {/foreach}
```